# ASP membership send registration HTML mail with image

Tags: html, asp.net, email

i have ASP.NET site with membership provider. when the user is registered i send mail for registration compilation with .txt file (containing HTML). i trying to add image to this HTML. the problem is that i cant see any image in the mail. 'images' folder is under main site folder.

Confermation.txt file

```
<body style='text-align:right;font-family:arial'>
<div style='margin:0 auto'>
    <img id="Image1" src="images/logo.png" style="width:350px;" />

    <br />
    please press the following link<br />
    <br />
    <a href="<%VerificationUrl%>">press here</a>
    <br /><br />
    Thanks 

</div>
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" EnableViewState="False"
            DisableCreatedUser="True" ID="CreateUserWizard1" Width="300px
            OnSendingMail="CreateUserWizard_SendingMail">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <CreateUserButtonStyle CssClass="btnRegister" Height="35px"></CreateUserButtonStyle>

            <MailDefinition From="myemail@gmail.com" 
                IsBodyHtml="True" Subject="registration" BodyFileName="Confermation.txt">
            </MailDefinition>
            <WizardSteps>
```

why cant i see the image?
i tried also `src="logo.png"` and `src="../images/logo.png"` with no success.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding html(browser type) coding in txt(simple text file) file. That can't be run or understand by browser. Use mail type html that can solve you problem